# INSERT only missing records from a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I do an `INSERT` in this way, but only insert the records that are not found in the table Cities?

```
CREATE TABLE #tCities (IDCity VARCHAR(10), NameCity VARCHAR(60))

INSERT INTO #tCities (IDCity, NameCity)
VALUES ('1','New York')

INSERT INTO #tCities (IDCity, NameCity)
VALUES ('2','Boston')
 

INSERT INTO Cities (ID_City, Name_City)
SELECT IDCity, NameCity
FROM #tCities A
LEFT JOIN Cities B ON A.IDCity = B.ID_City
WHERE A.IDCity IS NULL

DROP TABLE #tCities
```

Comment: Yes, I understand right now I do

Comment: Thank you very much, I am starting with SQL and could not find the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a join you can use `NOT EXISTS` e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Cities (ID_City, Name_City)
    SELECT IDCity, NameCity
    FROM #tCities A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Cities C WHERE C.ID_City = A.IDCity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  If you use `LEFT JOIN`, you want `#tCities` first.  And you want the `WHERE` to look at `Cities` for no match:

```
INSERT INTO Cities (ID_City, Name_City)
    SELECT t.IDCity,t. NameCity
    FROM #tCities t LEFT JOIN
         Cities c
         ON c.IDCity = t.ID_City
    WHERE c.IDCity IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `WHERE A.IDCity IS NULL` with `WHERE B.ID_City IS NULL` and there you go